# How to read SharePoint Online (Office365) Excel files into Python specifically pandas with Work or School Account?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sharepoint

The question is very similar to the link below. 
[How to read SharePoint Online (Office365) Excel files in Python with Work or School Account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48424045/how-to-read-sharepoint-online-office365-excel-files-in-python-with-work-or-sch/49461895#49461895)

Essentially I would like to import an excel file off SharePoint into pandas for further analysis.

The issue is when I run the code below I get the following error.

```
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\r\n<!DOCT'
```

My code:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.file import File 

url = 'https://companyname.sharepoint.com/SitePages/Home.aspx'
username = 'fakeaccount@company.com'
password = 'password!'
relative_url = '/Shared%20Documents/Folder%20Number1/Folder%20Number2/Folder3/Folder%20Number%Four/Target_Excel_File_v4.xlsx?d=w8f97c2341898_random_numbers_and_letters_a065c12cbcsf=1&e=KXoU4s'


ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
  ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
  web = ctx.web
  ctx.load(web)
  ctx.execute_query()
  #this gives me a KeyError: 'Title'
  #print("Web title: {0}".format(web.properties['Title']))
  print('Authentication Successful')
else:
  print(ctx_auth.get_last_error())


import io
import pandas as pd

response = File.open_binary(ctx, relative_url)

#save data to BytesIO stream
bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0) #set file object to start

#read file into pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For those of you that ended up like me here at this issue, I found that one has to path the full URL to `File`, not just the path:

```
#import all the libraries
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File 
import io
import pandas as pd

#target url taken from sharepoint and credentials
url = 'https://company.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Folder%20Number1/Folder%20Number2/Folder3/Folder%20Number4/Target_Excel_File_v4.xlsx?cid=_Random_letters_and_numbers-21dbf74c'
username = 'Dumby_account@company.com'
password = 'Password!'

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
  ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
  web = ctx.web
  ctx.load(web)
  ctx.execute_query()
  print("Authentication successful")

response = File.open_binary(ctx, url)

#save data to BytesIO stream
bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0) #set file object to start

#read excel file and each sheet into pandas dataframe 
df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj, sheetname = None)
```

Comment: Are you using Anaconda? I am trying to install office365 library in Anaconda (https://anaconda.org/jholdom/py-o365) and it fails.

Comment: @papelr That's not what comments are for nor how they work. Post your problem as a new question.

Comment: I didn't report your comment. I added a comment to help you get an answer.

Comment: i getting error  here `ctx.execute_query()` and `404 Client Error: Not Found for url myurl & _api\web` what is api/web? why it append it to my url?

Comment: @Angel Roman : getting error like 'AADSTS53003: Access has been blocked by Conditional Access policies. The access policy does not allow token issuance'. Any comment on how to get this resolved?

Comment: I copied this and i got the following error 'ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.' what can i do to fix?

Answer (score 8):

Maybe worth to note that the official repository holds many examples on common operations for sharepoint, drive and teams.

One note for installation:

> pip install Office365-REST-Python-Client

There is also a office365 package but the above one seems to be the correct one[enter link description here](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/files/download_file.py)

Comment: link is giving 404 error

Answer (score 3):

The following works with Client ID and Secret Code (Lib: Office365)

```
# Credential to connect to your SP Site
SITE_URL ='https://XXXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursitename'
CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
CLIENT_SECRET= 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# Establish the connection
context = ClientContext(SITE_URL).with_credentials(ClientCredential(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET))

response = File.open_binary(context, '/'.join(['/sites/yoursitename/Shared Documents/Work/OnlyFolderName', 
                                           'yourfilename.xlsx']))


df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(response.content))
```