# Read sharepoint excel file with python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sharepoint, office365

"I'm trying to use this code from [How to read SharePoint Online (Office365) Excel files into Python specifically pandas with Work or School Account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129328/how-to-read-sharepoint-online-office365-excel-files-into-python-specifically-p?rq=1) answers but a get the XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\r\n<!DOCT'. I think the problem is in the way im placing my path. Do anybody knows how to get this type of Sharepoint path, like in the example below?" The ones I get look more like this "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/site/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx"

```
#import all the libraries
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File 
import io
import pandas as pd

#target url taken from sharepoint and credentials
url = 'https://company.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Folder%20Number1/Folder%20Number2/Folder3/Folder%20Number4/Target_Excel_File_v4.xlsx?cid=_Random_letters_and_numbers-21dbf74c'
username = 'Dumby_account@company.com'
password = 'Password!'

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
  ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
  web = ctx.web
  ctx.load(web)
  ctx.execute_query()
  print("Authentication successful")

response = File.open_binary(ctx, url)

#save data to BytesIO stream
bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0) #set file object to start

#read excel file and each sheet into pandas dataframe 
df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj, sheetname = None)
```

Comment: This worked well for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I did it by opening the file in desktop and going to file > info > Copy Path. This path should work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using the share link instead of file path. You need to copy the correct path. Here's how:

1. Open the sharepoint folder
2. Click on the 3 dots in the file and click on Details
3. Scroll down and copy the Path
   the path should look something like: '/user/folder/Documents/Target_Excel_File_v4.xlsx'

Use the sharepoint url to authenticate and then use the copied path to open your binary file.

```
#import all the libraries
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File 
import io
import pandas as pd

#target url taken from sharepoint and credentials
url = 'https://company.sharepoint.com/user/folder'
path = '/user/folder/Documents/Target_Excel_File_v4.xlsx'
username = 'Dumby_account@company.com'
password = 'Password!'

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
  ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
  web = ctx.web
  ctx.load(web)
  ctx.execute_query()
  print("Authentication successful")

response = File.open_binary(ctx, path)

#save data to BytesIO stream
bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0) #set file object to start

#read excel file and each sheet into pandas dataframe 
df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj, sheet_name = None)
print(df)
```

Comment: TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sheetname'

Comment: @doubando There's a missing _. I have updated it with sheet_name.