# Connect to an excel from Sharepoint using python

Tags: python, excel, sharepoint

I want to Connect to an excel from Sharepoint using python but it doesnt work.

My code:

```
df = pd.read_excel(url,sheet_name = 'Sheet1', header = 0, auth=(username, password))
```

My error:

```
TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auth'
```

How can I connect?

find a solution at this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read sharepoint excel file with python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69488725/read-sharepoint-excel-file-with-python-pandas)

Comment: There are no `auth` argument there. Refer to the official document, ` pandas.read_excel(io, sheet_name=0, *, header=0, names=None, index_col=None, usecols=None, squeeze=None, dtype=None, engine=None, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint files are protected behing an authentification system, you first need to be able to connect to Sharepoint with your program using Sharepoint API before accessing the file.

See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/78034/how-to-connect-python-program-to-sharepoint-rest-a.html

[How to access a sharepoint site via the REST API in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945822/how-to-access-a-sharepoint-site-via-the-rest-api-in-python)