# How to read excel from SharePoint folder using python Pandas library

Tags: pandas, sharepoint

I'm attempting to read an Excel file from SharePoint using the office365 library in Python. I've tried the following code:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File 
import io
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://company.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/folder1/folder1/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%random_letters_and_numbers%7D&file=excel%20file%20name.xlsx&action=default&mobileredirect=true'
username = 'user.name@company.com'
password = 'password'

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
    ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
    web = ctx.web
    ctx.load(web)
    ctx.execute_query()
    print("Authentication successful")

response = File.open_binary(ctx, url)

bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0) 
df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj)
```

However, when I execute the code, I encounter the following error on the last line:

```
ValueError: File is not a recognized Excel file
```

Could someone please help me troubleshoot this issue? Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong in my code?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Try reading your byte stream and figuring out whether it is actually an Excel file being returned from the web.

Comment: @ifly6 How can I read the byte stream?

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted the code in the following links and works like a charm:

https://github.com/bashamsc/sharepoint_python/blob/main/sharepoint_read_file_python.py

[How to read SharePoint Online (Office365) Excel files into Python specifically pandas with Work or School Account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129328/how-to-read-sharepoint-online-office365-excel-files-into-python-specifically-p/55400643#55400643)

```
#Importing required libraries

from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File 

#Constrtucting SharePoint URL and credentials 

sharepoint_base_url = 'https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/sharepointname/'
sharepoint_user = 'user'
sharepoint_password = 'pwd'
folder_in_sharepoint = '/sites/sharepointname/FirstFolder/'

#Constructing Details For Authenticating SharePoint

auth = AuthenticationContext(sharepoint_base_url)

auth.acquire_token_for_user(sharepoint_user, sharepoint_password)
ctx = ClientContext(sharepoint_base_url, auth)
web = ctx.web
ctx.load(web)
ctx.execute_query()
print('Connected to SharePoint: ',web.properties['Title'])

   
#Constructing Function for getting file details in SharePoint Folder

def folder_details(ctx, folder_in_sharepoint):
  folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(folder_in_sharepoint)
  fold_names = []
  sub_folders = folder.files 
  ctx.load(sub_folders)
  ctx.execute_query()
  for s_folder in sub_folders:
    fold_names.append(s_folder.properties["Name"])
 return fold_names
 
#Getting folder details

file_list = folder_details(ctx, folder_in_sharepoint)

#Printing list of files from sharepoint folder
print(file_list)

#Reading File from SharePoint Folder
sharepoint_file = "/sites/sharepointname/FirstFolder/" + file.xlsx
file_response = File.open_binary(ctx, sharepoint_file)

response = file_response
st.write(response)

#save data to BytesIO stream
bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0) #set file object to start

#read excel file and each sheet into pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj, sheet_name="Sheet1", engine="openpyxl")
print(df)
```

Comment: Hello, an answer should be "standalone". References are great but insufficient. Solution should be explained in the post.