# connecting to sharepoint with python - Invalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed.', "500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url errors

Tags: python, sharepoint

I'm trying to connect to company sharepoint and use one of the example codes i found in this topic:

> [Accessing Microsoft Sharepoint files and data using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979467/accessing-microsoft-sharepoint-files-and-data-using-python/59981556#59981556)

the first lines of the code worked, I got "Authenticated into sharepoint as:********"

after I used this and it worked also

```
####Function for extracting the file names of a folder in sharepoint###
###If you want to extract the folder names instead of file names, you have to change "sub_folders = folder.files" to "sub_folders = folder.folders" in the below function
global print_folder_contents
def print_folder_contents(ctx, folder_url_shrpt):
    try:
       
        folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(folder_url_shrpt)
        fold_names = []
        sub_folders = folder.files #Replace files with folders for getting list of folders
        ctx.load(sub_folders)
        ctx.execute_query()
     
        for s_folder in sub_folders:
            
            fold_names.append(s_folder.properties["Name"])

        return fold_names

    except Exception as e:
        print('Problem printing out library contents: ', e)
```

Than I called the function to print the list of the elements with this code

```
# Call the function by giving your folder URL as input  
filelist_shrpt=print_folder_contents(ctx,folder_url_shrpt) 

#Print the list of files present in the folder
print(filelist_shrpt)
```

and I got this output:

"Problem printing out library contents:  ('-1, System.UriFormatException', 'Invalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed.', "500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: [https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/mysharepointpage/_api/Web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('https:%2F%2Fmycompany.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2FKmysharepointpage%2FDocuments%2520partages%2FGeneral%2F')/Files"](https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/mysharepointpage/_api/Web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(%27https:%2F%2Fmycompany.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2FKmysharepointpage%2FDocuments%2520partages%2FGeneral%2F%27)/Files%22))
None"

someone can help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a virtual printer driver that has a bidirectional integration to SharePoint. Here is a link to the download https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9NZL8MWS3MLG and here is a quick video https://vimeo.com/manage/videos/515880976