# Save Pandas or Pyspark dataframe from Databricks to SharePoint

Tags: pandas, azure, pyspark, sharepoint, databricks

How can I update a file on SharePoint with a Pandas or Pyspark dataframe from Databricks?

Is it possible or is the only option to upload the file from blob storage?

and if the upload is the only possible way, are there libraries to achieve that other than Office365-REST-Python-Client?

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, you cannot read share point data in azure databricks. SharePoint is not supported source in azure databricks.

More information refer this [Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/external-data/).

> Is there any alternative approach ?

yes, there are couple of alternative approaches:

- **Approach 1:**  Copy data from [SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list?tabs=data-factory) online list by using azure data factory.
- **Approach 2:** Using Python accessing SharePoint files and data .refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979467/accessing-microsoft-sharepoint-files-and-data-using-python) thread by Karthick Mohanraj.