# Using Python to access Excel File on Sharepoint using Office365 Python Module

Tags: python, excel, sharepoint

The goal of this code is to use Python to read an Excel file from a SharePoint folder using the Office365-REST-Python-Client 2.1.7.post1 module. I have worked with our IT Security Team to get ClientID and Client Secret codes for the authorization token and have verified they are working. But, whenever I attempt to access a given Excel file in a document library folder, I'm getting `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` errors.

Here's the code:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.file import File

credentials = {
    'credurl': 'https://portal.[COMPANYNAME].com/sites/documentlibrary',
    'client_id': '[CLIENT ID CODE]',
    'client_secret': '[CLIENT SECRET]',
}
relative_url = '/sites/documentlibrary/testfolder/Test-2020-05-01.xlsx'

context_auth = AuthenticationContext(url=credentials['credurl'])
context_auth.acquire_token_for_app(client_id=credentials['client_id'], client_secret=credentials['client_secret'])
ctx = ClientContext(credentials['credurl'], context_auth)

filename = 'output-2020-05-02.xlsx'
with open(filename, 'wb') as output_file:
    response = File.open_binary(ctx, relative_url)
    output_file.write(response.content)
```

The code errors our at the line `response = File.open_binary(ctx, relative_url).` Here's the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[NETWORK PATH]/Post-Test.py", line 46, in <module>
    response = File.open_binary(ctx=ctx, server_relative_url=relative_url)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\office365\sharepoint\file.py", line 201, in open_binary
    response = ctx.execute_request_direct(request)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_runtime_context.py", line 34, in execute_request_direct
    return self.pending_request.execute_request_direct(request)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_request.py", line 41, in execute_request_direct
    self.context.authenticate_request(request_options)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_runtime_context.py", line 15, in authenticate_request
    self.__auth_context.authenticate_request(request)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\auth\authentication_context.py", line 37, in authenticate_request
    request_options.set_header('Authorization', self.provider.get_authorization_header())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\auth\acs_token_provider.py", line 76, in get_authorization_header
    return 'Bearer {0}'.format(self.access_token["access_token"])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think the content on this page can help you! Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48424045/how-to-read-sharepoint-online-office365-excel-files-in-python-with-work-or-sch

Comment: I think this content can help! Check out this: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48424045/how-to-read-sharepoint-online-office365-excel-files-in-python-with-work-or-sch)

Comment: That's where I started. Even so, I can't get that solution to work. But thank you for responding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample that demonstrates how to download file from sharepoint using Office365-REST-Python-Client.

[File.open_binary](https://github.com/kongmengfei/sharedproject/blob/master/PythonConsole-uploadfileSPO/PythonApplication2/ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_app.py)