# Is there anyway to edit few cells in an excel file(.xlsb) and upload the edited excel file to sharepoint using python using clientcredentials?

Tags: python, excel, sharepoint, azure-functions

im working on collecting, editing and uploading a excel file of format.xlsb in python and upload the edited file into sharepoint.

I don't want to save it locally, as the code should runs on Azure functions. im able to collect the excel file from sharepoint in binary and work on it, but i want to edit the excel and upload the edited one to the same path using python or pyspark.

Any ideas of editing and uploading the file, can we do it in anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to save it locally

Yes you can edit the excel file without downloading it locally and the file from SharePoint try using [Office365-Rest-Python-Client](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client) API

Also here is the related [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49461895) over excel from SharePoint have a look

Comment: Thank you @SaiSakethGuduru-MT for answering, Yeah, im able to pull the excel file using that API, but im not able to add the DataFrame to that sheet and send back the edited sheet to SharePoint.